# Swing by Swing API Authorization

Tags: php, api

I am trying to log in to my app using the Swing by Swing api with this code:

```
<?php
header("location:https://api.swingbyswing.com/v2/oauth/authorize?
scope={read write}&
redirect_uri={http://pointcaddy.wcs8196admin.info}&
response_type={code}&
client_id={a18841bc-cca3-47d9-9dec-562571e28973}");
?>
```

Swing by Swing gives me an error that says "missing authorization request." I filled in this code like the docs say at https://api.swingbyswing.com/v2/getting-started, so what am I missing here?

Comment: Without your code what do you expect us to debug? The sections in the `{ }` need to be replaced with your values.

Comment: @Wobbles added the values.

Comment: Get rid of the curly brackets....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format the request without curly brackets as such:

```
<?php
header("location:https://api.swingbyswing.com/v2/oauth/authorize?scope=read write&redirect_uri=http://pointcaddy.wcs8196admin.info&response_type=code&client_id=a18841bc-cca3-47d9-9dec-562571e28973");
?>
```

The brackets only indicate variables you should replace.